# Why does Liesel ignore Max at first in "The Book Thief"?

Tags: character-analysis, markus-zusak, the-book-thief

In *The Book Thief* by Markus Zusak, Liesel Meminger and Max Vandenburg have an interesting relationship: at first, Liesel ignores Max and is hesitant to to talk to him. Then, for some reason, the two begin to get closer and closer and form a tight bond.

Why does Liesel ignore Max at first? Was it because she felt that Max replaced her brother? Was it because of how unexpected it was to hide a Jew in the house? Or was it something else?

Comment: I need an answer... :)